# How can I watch a Bool to see if its value changes, and then do something?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, boolean

I need to watch a BOOL and if it is YES I need to call a method.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is KVO - Key Value Observing. This Apple doc explains it well:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

Answer (score 0):

You read this article and come back to StackOverflow if you can't figure out how to get KVO to work: http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/

Answer (score 0):

You could also override the method that changes the property's value:

```
-(void)setMyBool:(BOOL)myBool{
    _myBool=myBool;

    //if the Boolean is yes then do doMyAction.
    if(_myBool){
        [self doMyAction]
    }
}
```